# Enforcing a specific HTML element type with prop-types?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-proptypes

When a component expects a prop of certain type of HTML element (not a React class), i.e. `HTMLSpanElement`, I would like the propTypes definition of the component to enforce that.

Tried `PropTypes.instanceOf(HTMLSpanElement)` and `oneOf([HTMLSpanElement])` I've seen suggested, nothing seems to work although the element is an instance of the defined constructor - Prop types claim it's an object.

Demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/y348wqvxlx).

Answer (score 1):

Following Alvin's comment here's what works for me without custom validators:

```js
videoTag: PropTypes.shape({
  tagName: PropTypes.oneOf(['VIDEO']),
})
```

Still not sure if that's the easiest way possible though.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom PropType validator which checks the prop children to make sure that it is just a basic HTML element. Your code might look like this:

```
const htmlElementPropType = (props, propName, componentName) => {
  const value = props[propName]
  const validHTMLElementTags = ['div', 'span', 'a', 'p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4']
  if ((typeof value.type != 'string') ||
      validHTMLElementTags.indexOf(value.type.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
    return new TypeError(`Invalid HTML Element Prop Value: ${propName} in ${componentName}`)
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  children: htmlElementPropType
};
```

The first to note is that, when you pass your children on to `App`, the JSX that you pass (whether that's `<span>Hello World</span>` or `<MyComponent />`) will show up in your custom validator and be findable as `props[propName]`. That's what you're seeing as `value` in the first line of the validator.

You want to check `typeof value.type`. If it is equal to `function`, then we're dealing with a React component; but if it's `string`, then we're dealing with a built-in component (a basic HTML element). So, it may be enough for you to simply check `typeof value.type` to ensure it's a `string`. If you want additional restrictions - for example, only allowing *certain* HTML Elements - then you can add those, as in my code sample above.

That should be enough to get you started. I forked your code sandbox and then added in my sample code to test. You can play around by changing the children passed to `App`. For example, try to use the quickly made `<MyComponent>` and test how the prop type validator reacts to that.

[image: Edit custom prop type]

---

Here are some helpful resources on PropTypes and custom validators:

- [ReactJS Documentation on typechecking](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)
- [Article on Medium.com on Custom PropType Validation](https://medium.com/@jaebradley/custom-react-prop-type-validation-8b48dc3a156)

Comment: Thank you!

I've played with custom propTypes checking before, and it's powerful but I think this should probably be covered by a simple `instanceOf(Constructor)` - And such a custom validator would have to support passing the expected constructor, which  sounds to me like recreating `instanceOf`, no?

Comment: I get what you're saying. It makes sense. But, I believe that, at the point that proptypes is checking the prop, you're getting whatever the result is of [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement), and that's always just an object with a `type`, some `props`, and some `children`.

Comment: You could do `instanceOf(Object)`, but that would pass regardless of if it's an HTML element or a React Component (both need to passed through to `React.createElement`), so that's useless to you. This object has not yet been rendered to the DOM, so you can't really check if it's an `HTMLSpanElement` or any other type of DOM element. While you're in this post-created-but-pre-rendered state, your best option is to check the object's `type`. Hope that helps!